# How should I configure Jackson to produce XML using the @XmlRootElement on list items

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a `Spring-MVC` `@RestController` that uses generic names rather than the names I have configured with `@XmlRootElement` or `@JacksonXmlRootElement`. I want `XML` to look like this:

```
<list>
  <foo>
    <name>John</name>
  </foo>
</list>
```

but I get the following:

```
<ArrayList>
  <item>
    <name>John</name>
  </item>
</ArrayList>
```

Marshalling a single instance correctly looks like this:

```
<foo>
  <name>John</name>
</foo>
```

To try and solve this, I've tried using both `Jackson` and `JAXB` annotations. I've also conducted an extensive search for someone else's solution on Stack Overflow, various blogs, and issues reported against `Jackson` and `Spring-mvc`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.junit.Test;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;

public class JacksonXmlTest {

    @XmlRootElement(name="foo")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Foo {
        private String name;

        public Foo(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void understandListTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // This is a JUnit test.....
        List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
        fooList.add(new Foo("John"));

        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        System.err.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(fooList));
        System.err.println();
        System.err.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(fooList.get(0)));
    }

}
```

Please help me configure jackson to output the list wrapped in "list" tags and have each Foo object contained in "foo" tags rather than "item" tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class ListFoo that contains a list of Foo Object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="list")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ListFoo {

    @XmlElement(name = "foo")
    private List<Foo> listFoo;

    // getters & setters

 }
```

Comment: Yes, that will work. However, then in my spring controller I'm stuck implementing separate methods for JSON and XML because I need to create this wrapper class for XML. Is that as good as it gets?

Answer (score 1):

Using [MixIn](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature you can define name for an `ArrayList` class and others from `java.util.*`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.addMixIn(ArrayList.class, ArrayListMixIn.class);
        xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item());
        items.add(new Item());
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(items));
    }
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "list")
interface ArrayListMixIn {
}

class Item {

    private String name = "random - " + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<list>
  <item>
    <name>random - 0.2256442724594785</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>random - 0.9958813192003821</name>
  </item>
</list>
```

Comment: Can a Mix-In help with the <item> tag as well?

Comment: @TimPerry, Unfortunately it is hardcoded in [XmlSerializerProvider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/ser/XmlSerializerProvider.java) class. Take a look at `_startRootArray` method. You can of course try to override it but I do not see simple way how to achieve this. Probably the simplest way would be implementing custom serialiser for a list but it also looks complicated.

Comment: @TimPerry, See example for another problem: [Using Jackson to add XML attributes to manually-built node-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060797/using-jackson-to-add-xml-attributes-to-manually-built-node-tree)

Comment: Interesting link. I'll have to think about which one will be more maintainable. I'm leaning towards the wrapper @tcharaf suggested. Thanks for the food for thought!