# Spring Boot adding attribute to XML element but NOT in JSON response

Tags: json, xml, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I am working on an `API` that produces both XML and JSON responses. I have one element in the response which requires an attribute only in XML response. Also, when the value is `null`, the element shouldn't show up in the response for both formats.

Expectation:
XML:

```
<name>john</name>
<status type="text">married</status>
```

JSON:

```
"name":"john"
"status":"married"
```

This is my code:

```java
    /**
     * POJO with bunch of LOMBOK annotations to avoid boiler-plate code.
     */
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @Data
    public class User implements Customer, Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Status status;
        private String name;

        /**
         * Matrital status of the user.
         */
        @Builder
        @Value
        public static class Status {

            @JacksonXmlText
            private String maritalStatus;

            @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
            private String type = "text";
        }

    }
```

With the above change, I am getting the correct XML response but JSON response also returns `type=text`

```
 "status" : {
    "maritalStatus" : "married",
    "type" : "text"
  }
```

I tried to add `@JsonValue` to `private String maritalStatus`, that solved the JSON response but it broke XML response by not adding the attribute to the element.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Could you please state that you're using Lombok? Not everybody is familiar with this bunch of annotations.
Also, Instead of `@JsonValue` you could try using `@JsonProperty` together with the xml anotation

Comment: Added that I am using Lombok. Thanks for pointing that out. `@JsonProperty` didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to marshalling an object one way in XML, but another in JSON (different fields, etc.) was to use "mixins".
One trick is that you have to manually register the mixin, there's no magic. See below.

Mixin interface:

```
public interface UserStatusXmlMixin {

    @JsonValue(false)
    @JacksonXmlText
    String getStatus();

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    String getType();
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Value
public class UserStatus implements UserStatusXmlMixin {

    private String status;

    @JsonValue
    @Override
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "text";
    }

    /**
     * Returns an unmodifiable UserStatus when status is available, 
     * otherwise return null. This will help to remove this object from the responses.
     */
    public static UserStatus of(final String status) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(status)
                       .map(UserStatus::new)
                       .orElse(null);
    }

}
```

I also had to register the "mixin" manually.

```
@Configuration
public class AppJacksonModule extends SimpleModule {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;

    private final Map<Class, Class> mixinByTarget;

    /**
     * Construct an AppJacksonModule.
     */
    public AppJacksonModule() {
        super("AppJacksonModule");
        this.mixinByTarget = Map.of(
                UserStatus.class, UserStatusXmlMixin.class
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(final SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        final ObjectCodec contextOwner = context.getOwner();
        if (contextOwner instanceof XmlMapper) {
            mixinByTarget.forEach(context::setMixInAnnotations);
        }
    }
```

Now wherever I needed to create UserStatus using `UserStatus.of(..)` if the input param is null, `<status/>` won't show up in the response.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(status).map(UserStatus::new).orElse(null)`? Perhaps I’m getting old, but how is that better than `status == null ? null : new UserStatus(status)`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to implement custom serialiser for `User.Status` and produce different output for different kinds of representation.

```java
class UserStatusJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User.Status> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(User.Status value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (gen instanceof ToXmlGenerator) {
            ToXmlGenerator toXmlGenerator = (ToXmlGenerator) gen;
            serializeXml(value, toXmlGenerator);
        } else {
            gen.writeString(value.getMaritalStatus());
        }
    }

    private void serializeXml(User.Status value, ToXmlGenerator toXmlGenerator) throws IOException {
        toXmlGenerator.writeStartObject();

        toXmlGenerator.setNextIsAttribute(true);
        toXmlGenerator.writeFieldName("type");
        toXmlGenerator.writeString(value.getType());
        toXmlGenerator.setNextIsAttribute(false);
        toXmlGenerator.writeRaw(value.getMaritalStatus());

        toXmlGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, User.Status value) {
        return value == null || value.getMaritalStatus() == null;
    }
}
```

Since now, you can remove extra `XML` annotations and register custom serialiser:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Status status;
    private String name;

    @Builder
    @Value
    @JsonSerialize(using = UserStatusJsonSerializer.class)
    public static class Status {
        private String maritalStatus;
        private String type = "text";
    }
}
```

Simple console app usage could look like below:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(
                createUser("John", "married"),
                createUser("Tom", null));

        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
                .build();
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(user));
            System.out.println();
        }

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
                .build();
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(user));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static User createUser(String name, String maritalStatus) {
        return User.builder()
                .name(name)
                .status(User.Status.builder()
                        .maritalStatus(maritalStatus)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

#### Above code prints

JSON for John:

```
{
  "status" : "married",
  "name" : "John"
}
```

JSON for Tom:

```
{
  "name" : "Tom"
}
```

XML for John:

```
<User>
  <status type="text">married</status>
  <name>John</name>
</User>
```

XML for Tom

```
<User>
  <name>Tom</name>
</User>
```

Notice, that we implemented `UserStatusJsonSerializer#isEmpty` method which defines what `empty` means for a `Status` class. Now, we need to enable `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` feature in your `Spring Boot` application. Add below key to your application configuration file:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_empty
```

If you do not want to enable inclusion globally you can enable it only for one property using `@JsonInclude` annotation.

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private Status status;
```

See also:

- [Using Jackson to add XML attributes to manually-built node-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060797/using-jackson-to-add-xml-attributes-to-manually-built-node-tree)
- [How to tell Jackson to ignore a field during serialization if its value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757487/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-field-during-serialization-if-its-value-is-null)
- [Spring Boot: Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Comment: Thanks, Michal. I found another way to solve this issue.. But I was going to try your way of using a custom serializer if my "mixin" way would have failed. See my answer.